# Software for processing laser scanner images

Tags: software, scanning

I have a Ciclop laser 3d scanner, sold as a kit (HE3D), that I've had for several months now without being able to use it, because the official Horus software is completely unmaintained and bitrotted - the API for several Python modules it depends on has changed out from under it, and it looks like the v4l2 interface (or perhaps OpenCV's interface to it) for the camera has also changed in ways that it doesn't grok. I could try to setup an outdated system or VM just to run it, but I'd rather avoid having to use it completely.

In principle, it seems like you should just be able to step the stage, taking images with the laser on and off at each step and differencing them, and feeding those images into the numerical algorithms that construct a point cloud and model. Are there any free software tools that can take and process this kind of input? If so, I can handle scripting the sampling.